# validação email e senha sendo iguais e com o minimo de caracteres

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masked-input

olá, sou iniciando no mundo do jquery e estou trabalhando com djando e python e o formulário tem o jquery abaixo

```
 <script>
 $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
 $('#senha2').on('keyup', function () {
 var password = $("#senha").val();
 var confirmPassword = $("#senha2").val();

 if (password != confirmPassword) {
     $("#divCheckPassword").html("As senhas não são").css('color', 'red');
     $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
 } else {
    $("#divCheckPassword").html("Senhas identicas").css('color', 'green');
    $('#validator').prop('disabled' , false);
 }
});
 </script>
```

e ele funciona perfeitamente ele só ativa o botão do formulário se ambos emails tiverem certos, mas preciso que ele faça isso usando o email e tbm o iinpput da senha e para piorar preciso que ele seja configurado para que a senha tenha no minimo 8 caracteres e no máximo 16 e que os campos email sejam considerados iguais apenas se os emails forem validos.
Queria que fosse sendo validado enquanto se digita

acho que quero muito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (password.length < 8 || password.length > 16) { 
     $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
 }     

if (password != confirmPassword) {
         $("#divCheckPassword").html("As senhas não são").css('color', 'red');
         $('#validator').prop('disabled' , true);
     } else {
        $("#divCheckPassword").html("Senhas identicas").css('color', 'green');
        $('#validator').prop('disabled' , false);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar as validações do HTML5, como por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="password" maxlength="16" minLength="8">

<input type="email" name="email">
```